# Heat Capacity of Ferromagnets and Antiferromagnets

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, ferromagnetism

I want to calculates (at least qualitatively) the heat capacities of a *ferromagnet* and an *antiferromagnet*, say on a cubic lattice so life is simple. I want to make sure my approach is legit and also ask how to deal with certain regimes.

**Ferromagnets:**

- Low Temperature $T\ll T_c$:  I think in the regimes one uses the dispersion of *magnons*, $\omega_k = Ak^2$, recognizes these are *bosonic* quasi-particles and from there it's easy.
- $T\sim T_c$: Here Landau-Ginzburg tells us that phenomenologically $f=tm^2+um^4$, which leads to a discontinuous heat capacity at $T=T_c$.
- High temperature? This is a bit confusing for me. In reality in high temperature a ferromagnet becomes a paramagnet. Then each spin is independent of any other and therefore heat capacity is zero? What if $T>T_c$ but not $\gg T_c$?

**Antiferromagnets:**

- $T\ll T_c$ is similar to ferromagnets, just the magnons now have two linear branches (instead of one quadratic one)
- I have no idea what happens around $T\sim T_c$.
- Seems to me very high temperature should be the same as ferromagnetic case, but the intermediate temperatures, i.e. $T>T_c$ but not $\gg T_c$, are a complete mystery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the heat capacities in the **low temperature** *ferromagnetic* (FM) and *antiferromagnetic* (AFM) phases are correct. At the **critical point**, things get tricky because there are critical fluctuations that one has to go beyond the mean-field description and use *renormalization groups* or *scaling arguments* to understand the singularity of heat capacity around the critical point. But in the **high temperature** phase, things get simple again. There is only one single phase in the high-temperature regime: the *paramagnetic* (PM) phase. In this phase, the spins are disordered and the coupling $J$ is irrelevant in the RG sense, so there are no real distinctions between ferromagnets and antiferromagnets in the PM phase. The heat capacity $C$ always decay with the temperature $T$ as

$$C\sim \frac{NJ^2}{k_B T^2}+\mathcal{O}[T^{-3}],$$

where $J$ is the (effective) spin-spin interaction strength which depends on the microscopic model details.

This form of the specific heat can be argued from general principles of *thermodynamics*. Let us start from the infinite temperature ($T\to\infty$) limit, where the spins are completely uncorrelated and random. Each individual spin will contribute a finite amount of entropy $s_0$. For example, each Ising spin will give $s_0=k_B \ln 2$ at $T\to\infty$. So the total entropy $S_0=Ns_0$ will be a constant independent of the temperature. As the spins are uncorrelated, the internal energy vanishes as $U_0=0$, so the free energy should be $F_0=U_0-TS_0=-TNs_0$, from which the heat capacity $C_0\equiv -T \partial_T^2 F_0=0$ is zero as expected. Now if we go away from the $T\to\infty$ limit, the free energy should receive some correction order by order from the high-temperature expansion (i.e. we expand the free energy $F(T)$ as a power series of $1/T$):

$$F=F_0+F_1 \left(\frac{J}{k_B T}\right)+F_2 \left(\frac{J}{k_B T}\right)^2+\cdots.$$

Obviously, $J/k_BT$ is the only dimensionless small parameter that controls the high-temperature expansion (because $J$ is the only energy scale in the system to cancle the dimension of $k_BT$). Because the spins are disordered in the PM phase, so $J<0$ (FM coupling) and $J>0$ (AFM coupling) should not make a difference (before the loop diagram appears in the high-temperature expansion). Therefore we know that the linear terms in $J$ must vanish in the free energy, i.e. $F_1=0$. By dimensional analysis, we can show that $F=F_0-aNJ^2/(k_BT)+\cdots$ where $a$ is a dimensionless constant that can be absorbed to the (re)definition of an effective coupling $J$. From this form of the free energy, the heat capacity of the lowest order of $1/T$ in the PM phase can be derived and the result is just as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. Do both heat capacity vs. temperature diagrams look like a $\lambda$? Also is there a way of writing an effective model Hamiltonian in high temperature regime to see this $1/T^2$ dependence clearly?

Comment: @Hamed 2D Ising model is one specific model that exhibits the $1/T^2$ heat capacity in the high-temperature regime. I found this web page useful: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node110.html